# Automate the weekly update of worksheet data and graphs

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with two Excel 2013 workbook tabs: "Metrics" and "Chart Date". The Metrics worksheet holds both eight graphs plus data that's fed into it via other worksheets. The Chart Data worksheet holds rows of data (one row for each consecutive week) received from the Metrics tab. My problem is that I'm trying to figure out how to take the rows of data in the Chart Data worksheet and run a macro that will update it each week (like change 32 to 33 the next week, then 34 the next week, and so forth, each time the Metrics tab is updated. I also need to be able to update the graphs. This is the code I currently have:

```
Sub UpdateChartData()

'Appends the new data from the "Metrics" tab of workbook to the Chart Data tab, appending a new row for each week.
    Sheets("Chart Data").Select

    Range("A32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("B32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[1]"
    Range("C32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C"
    Range("D32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-1]"
    Range("E32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-2]"
    Range("H32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("J32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[-6]"
    Range("K32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-7]"
    Range("L32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-8]"
    Range("N32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7"'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("P32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[-11]"
    Range("Q32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-12]"
    Range("R32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-13]"
    Range("T32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("U32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[17]"
    Range("V32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[16]"
    Range("W32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[15]"
    Range("X32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[14]"
    Range("AA32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("AB32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[13]"
    Range("AC32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[12]"
    Range("AD32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[11]"
    Range("AE32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[10]"
    Range("AH32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" ' Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("AI32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[-25]"
    Range("AJ32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[-26]"
    Range("AK32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-27]"
    Range("AL32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-28]"
    Range("AO32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("AP32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[-15]"
    Range("AQ32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[-16]"
    Range("AR32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-17]"
    Range("AS32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-18]"
    Range("AV32").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days to the previous week's date.
    Range("AW32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[-24]"
    Range("AX32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C[-25]"
    Range("AY32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-26]"
    Range("AZ32").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-27]"

    UpdateCharts
End Sub
```

'############################################################################

```
Sub UpdateCharts()

    '   Updates the charts based on the data that was updated in the "Chart Data" tab for given week.
        Sheets("Metrics").Select

        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("A1:F32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("H2:L32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("N2:R32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("T2:Y32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("AV2:BA32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("AO2:AT32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("AH2:AM32")
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("AA2:AF32")

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should help you get started:

```
Sub UpdateChartData()

' Appends the new data from the "Metrics" tab of workbook
' to the Chart Data tab, appending a new row for each week.
    Dim r As Range

    'find the first empty row in ColA (working up from the bottom of the sheet)
    Set r = Sheets("Chart Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With r.EntireRow
        'here we're using .Range("A1") *relative* to the row
        '  we're working on: Eg Range("A8").Range("A1") is A8
        .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+7" 'Adds 7 days
        .Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-30]C[1]"
        .Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-29]C"
        .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-1]"
        .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-2]"
        '............
        'etc. etc....
        '............
        .Range("AY1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-18]C[-26]"
        .Range("AZ1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Metrics!R[-8]C[-27]"
    End With

    UpdateCharts r.Row 'pass the just-filled row number

End Sub

Sub UpdateCharts(rw As Long)

' Updates the charts based on the data that was updated
'   in the "Chart Data" tab for given week. Sheets("Metrics").Select
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Chart Data")
    'No need to Activate any charts - you can work directly with them
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("A1:F" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("H2:L" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("N2:R" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("T2:Y" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("AV2:BA" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("AO2:AT" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("AH2:AM" & rw)
    sht.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("AA2:AF" & rw)

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, this is awesome. The only question I have now is - when I'm running the code, one I reach the first line of the UpdateCharts(rw As Long), I receive a Run-time error 2147024809 (80070057) message that states "The item with specified name wasn't found." I'm not sure what that means, so I'm not sure how to fix it. Other than that, this is amazing!

Comment: Sounds like one of those names is not found?

Comment: What name? I'm still new to this and don't know what that means. It's on this line that the message appears:  "sht.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("A1:E" & rw)"

Comment: Seems like you don't have a chart called "Chart 8" on your "Chart Data" worksheet

Comment: Tim, it works! As long as I activate the charts, for whatever reason, it all works. Your code is awesome. Thank you SO much!

Comment: I have another question based on a different, but similar, macro I'm writing. If, for example, I need to take this code:        sht.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=sht.Range("N2:R" & rw)      
and use columns  N and R only, no O and P, how would I word that? I've tried various things, but nothing seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: `Source:=sht.Range("N2:N" & rw & ",R2:R" & rw)` should do it.

Comment: Thanks. Tim. I'm not getting it to work, probably b/c I'm activating the chart - maybe? This is what I tried:         ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 12").Activate  -next line-     ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart Data").Range("N1:N" & rw & ",R1:R" & rw)

Comment: Try recording a macro while setting that source range and check the code produced.  Possibly you need a semicolon in place of the comma (depends on your computers location setting)